# Eclips projects: keeping an old version and working on a new one

Tags: android, eclipse, version, project, revision

Maybe a stupid question but here it goes:

1. I have Eclipse with Egit installed. My system is a Windows Vista based PC.
2. I have a project named "HelloWorld" (android app) working to my satisfaction now.
3. I want to mess with it to try/add something with/to it.
4. I want to keep the current "HelloWorld" project intact so that if something terribly goes wrong, I can go back to it.
5. I want to make a copy of the current HelloWorld" project and rename the project "HelloWold001" or something like that and mess with it.

This is for my personal educational purpose, so I won't be sharing it with anybody. What's the simplest way to achieve this without using Egit or anything like that?

Thank you for your help.

================================================================================
Update (July 19, 2014):

Thanks to comments posted here and elsewhere (mostly on stackoverflow) and answers to my related questions from AndroidWarrior, I think I've managed to come up with a decent way to accomplish what I wanted.

Here it is:

Phase 1: Make a copy of your project.

1. In Package Explorer, right-click on the project you want to make a copy of. (Make sure the project is open.)
2. Click on “Copy.”
3. Click on “Paste.” In the dialog window that follows, click “OK.” (Do not type in the new name for your copied project in this phase. You will change the project name in Phase 2.)
4. You should get a copy of your project in Package Explorer, named “Copy of [your old project name].”

Phase 2: Change the name of the copied project and “Refactor.”

1. Right-click on the copied project name in Package Explorer, select “Refactor” and type in the new name for the copied project.

Phase 3: Change the package name of the copied project.

1. Right-click on the copied project name, select “Android Tools” ==> “Rename Application Package” and click.
2. Change the package name and click “OK.”

This phase should take care of changing a reference in Manifest file so that you don't have to do it manually:

Phase 4:  Change references to the package name in your copied project, like the statements in your other files, such as “package [your old package name] “ in java files, etc.

1. Right-click on the package name in the project ( under “src” is the one I use) and select “Refactor” ==> “Rename” to change the package name to what you changed to in Phase 3 above, and click “OK.” Make sure the box for “Update references” is checked.
2. At this point, all “package [your package name];” statements in your java source files and gen files should be changed to reflect the new package name.

If you want to change the app name, you need to manually change the “App name string” value in the strings.xml file.

One thing I'm not sure about is whether Phase 2 is necessary if you type in the final project name in Phase 1.

Comment: Why not keep working in your current project, but just save a backup somewhere?

Comment: Go into your workspace, copy the project folder and save it somewhere.

Comment: To Simon: I'd like to keep the original and the new version both in workplace so that I can compare them easily. (I may make minor changes to the original to test something, too.)

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a project with name "HelloWorld1"
2. Copy all the files and assets under the same hierarchy.
3. Change your package name to some other name.

OR

You could keep a backup of your project and keep working on the same.

Comment: AndroidWarrior, while I think your method is likely to work, I've tried the following method:

Comment: continuation: Package Explore, select the original project ==> copy ==> paste with new project name. Rename the package name in the copy's Manifest. Refactor the new project. This seems to work; however, I cannot change package statements in the new java source files. Will this cause a serious problem later?

Comment: I'm writing Android apps. I have 5 Java files in the first (original) program, and they all have "package com.example.android.opengl;" as the first Java statement. In the copied project, I can change the package name in its Manifest, but not the package name in the above statements. (They become errors if I change them.) The copied project compiles and runs on Bluestacks fine. I'm just wondering if it's safe to go on like this. I don't see any point in being able to change the package name in Manifest, but not in any of these "package" statements.

Comment: @Janinzah You need to change the package name in the folder structure hierarchy, then you can change the package name in your java file as well and it won't give you any errors and yes changing package name in manifest is a must.

Comment: How do you change the package name in the folder structure hierarchy? I changed the folder in src directory to "opnegl002" from "opengl" and changed all 5 "package" statements to reflect that change. The program compiled but did nothing (crashed). I restored the original folder name "opengl" and the 5 "package" statements to reflect that. Now the program compiles and runs as before.

Comment: @Janinzah In your project `Package -> Rightclick -> Refactor -> Rename`. It'll automatically handle it's references for you.